# How can I exclude pages created from a specific template from the CQ5 dispatcher cache?

Tags: caching, dispatcher, aem, day-cq

I have a specific Adobe CQ5 (5.5) content template that authors will use to create pages.  I want to exclude any page that is created from this template from the dispatcher cache.  As I understand it currently, the only way I know to prevent caching is to configure **dispatcher.any** to *not* cache a particular URL.  But in this case, the URL isn't known until a web author uses the template to create a page.  I don't want to have to go back and modify dispatcher.any every time a page is created--or at least I want to automate this if there is no other way.  I am using IIS for the dispatcher.  The reason I don't want to cache the pages is because the underlying JSPs that render the content for these pages produce dynamic content, and the pages don't use querystrings and won't carry authentication headers.  The pages will be created in unpredictable directories, so I don't know the URL pattern ahead of time.

**How can I configure things so that *any* page that is created from a certain template will be automatically excluded from the dispatcher cache?**

It seems like CQ ought to have some mechanism to respect HTTP response/caching headers.  If the HTTP response headers specify that the response shouldn't be cached, it seems like the dispatcher shouldn't cache it--regardless of what dispatcher.any says.  This is [the CQ5 documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/dispatcher.html) I have been referencing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the IIS verson of the Dispatcher, but certainly with the Apache module if you add a custom HTTP header "dispatcher: nocache" it will not cache the page in the Dispatcher. You would need to change the code to add this, which would be something like:

```
    request.setHeader("Dispatcher", "nocache");
```

It might also work as meta tags in the html, but I've not tried this.

This is documented here: http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/Dispatcher/faq-s/DispatcherNoCache.html

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might use cache control tags in the template's head.   See info on PRAGMA and Cache-Control meta tags here: [HTTP Cache- Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360283/http-cache-control).